# How to properly test Hibernate length restriction?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have a POJO mapped with Hibernate for persistence. In my mapping I specify the following:

```
<class name="ExpertiseArea">
    <id name="id" type="string">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <version name="version" column="VERSION" unsaved-value="null" />
    <property name="name" type="string" unique="true" not-null="true" length="100" />
    ...
</class>
```

And I want to test that if I set a name longer than 100 characters, the change won't be persisted. I have a DAO where I save the entity with the following code:

```
public T makePersistent(T entity){
    transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    try{
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        transaction.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        transaction.rollback();
    }   
    return entity;
}
```

Actually the code above is from a GenericDAO which all my DAOs inherit from. Then I created the following test:

```
public void testNameLengthMustBe100orLess(){
    ExpertiseArea ea = new ExpertiseArea(
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890" +
        "1234567890");

    assertTrue("Name should be 100 characters long", ea.getName().length() == 100);

    ead.makePersistent(ea);
    List<ExpertiseArea> result = ead.findAll();
    assertEquals("Size must be 1", result.size(),1);

    ea.setName(ea.getName()+"1234567890");
    ead.makePersistent(ea);

    ExpertiseArea retrieved = ead.findById(ea.getId(), false);
    assertTrue("Both objects should be equal", retrieved.equals(ea));
    assertTrue("Name should be 100 characters long", (retrieved.getName().length() == 100));
}
```

The object is persisted ok. Then I set a name longer than 100 characters and try to save the changes, which fails:

```
14:12:14,608  INFO StringType:162 - could not bind value '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890' to parameter: 2; data exception: string data, right truncation
14:12:14,611  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: -3401, SQLState: 22001
14:12:14,611 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - data exception: string data, right truncation
14:12:14,614 ERROR AbstractFlushingEventListener:324 - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update: [com.exp.model.ExpertiseArea#33BA7E09-3A79-4C9D-888B-4263314076AF]

//Stack trace

14:12:14,615 DEBUG GenericDAO:87 - could not update: [com.exp.model.ExpertiseArea#33BA7E09-3A79-4C9D-888B-4263314076AF]
14:12:14,616 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:186 - rollback
14:12:14,616 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:197 - rolled back JDBC Connection
```

That's expected behavior. However when I retrieve the persisted object to check if its name is still 100 characters long, the test fails.

The way I see it, the retrieved object should have a name that is 100 characters long, given that the attempted update failed. The last assertion fails because the name is 110 characters long now, as if the `ea` instance was indeed updated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try clearing the session, it may be a caching problem.

Comment: I really would like your comment to be an answer instead, because that was exactly the problem. Thanks lexicore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the object is first stored in the session (and cached) and on failure it is not evicted. You you'd have to `session.evict(..)` it. Other options are `session.clear(..)` and `session.refresh(..)` to make sure you are working with what's in the database.

What you have is a database restriction, no hibernate. If you don't want to hit the database at all, you can use [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html)'s `@Length` annotation. ([Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator) is a fresh article)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the suggestion on using Hibernate Validators. I'm accepting this answer as accepted.